# Why is my .Net 6 Web API is returning 401

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-401

I have a react UI that consumes the Web API. Actually the react UI exists within the same project as the API Controllers. Everything works fine as long as the API Controllers DO NOT have an `[Authorize]` attribute.

However, with `[Authorize]`, I am seeing the API(s) returning http 401 errors. And this is where my question(s) begin - why 401?

I have done the following things:

- In Azure AD app, under API Permissions, I added 3 permissions (Azure.Storage user_impersonation, Microsoft.Graph User.Read, and my web API access_as_user).
- When the UI makes a request to an API, I am adding a header with the Authorization bearer token. Here is the screenshot of that:

  [image]
- I obtain the access token using `PublicClientApplication`'s `acquireTokenSilent` method
- I obtain the access token using this scope

Note: in the 401 response, I see this message that suggests the tokens is incorrect. Why is the token bad?

[image]

```
let scopes: string[] = [`${process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID}/.default`];
```

Comment: Have you tried console.logging your token and using postman?   It could be a lot of things, but my guess is CORS, although it seems they are in the same app (and therefore served from the same host and port?).   No type of authentication is even attempted without the Authorize attribute.

Comment: Yeah, the purpose of doing this (other than security) is to be able to obtain the user's identity in the Web APIs (for logging purposes).

Comment: Have you tested it in postman? You can see why the token is invalid in postman.

Comment: check IIS for allowing OPTIONS header, as this will trigger preflight request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that I was generating/using the wrong access token.